# JPanel paintComponent not working properly

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I learned that if you override

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
```

You can get an image painted as the background of a class that extends javax.swing.JPanel.
In my code I have 2 instances of the same Class extending JPanel with almost exactly the same code just with a different position and background image in a second JPanel and while one gets the background the other one does not. Here is my code:

```
public class CardPanel extends JPanel {

    private int x, y, width, height;
    private BufferedImage background;

    public CardPanel(int x, int y, int width, int height, BufferedImage background) {

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.background = background;

        createCardPanel();

    }

    private void createCardPanel() {

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        setFocusable(false);
        setOpaque(true);

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(background, x, y, null);

    }

}
```

And how I use it:

```
pCardPanel = new CardPanel();
dCardPanel = new CardPanel();
```

Declaring the CardPanels

```
private void createCardPanels(String imgPath) {

        BufferedImage background = ImageLoader.loadImage(imgPath);

        pCardPanel = new CardPanel(0, (height - Card.CARD_HEIGHT), width, Card.CARD_HEIGHT, background.getSubimage(0, (height - Card.CARD_HEIGHT), width, Card.CARD_HEIGHT));
        dCardPanel = new CardPanel(0, 0, width, Card.CARD_HEIGHT, background.getSubimage(0, 0, width, Card.CARD_HEIGHT));

        this.add(pCardPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.add(dCardPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    }
```

Method for creating and adding the CardPanels

```
createCardPanels("/textures/background.png");
```

Using the method

```
public void addCardImage(BufferedImage img, boolean playerCard) {

        JLabel imgLabel = new JLabel();
        ImageIcon icon;
        icon = new ImageIcon(img);
        imgLabel.setIcon(icon);
        cardImages.add(imgLabel);
        if (playerCard)
            pCardPanel.add(imgLabel);
        else
            dCardPanel.add(imgLabel);
        display.pack();

    }
```

This last method is called for adding Card Images to te panel, this part works.                                   Now to my problem:
[this is how it looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yakd5.png) (there are some other flaws like the card position but this will be a later issue I can fix myself)
As you can see, the panel on the bottom (pCardPanel) has no background image.                            Any ideas why it might be this way? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can get an image painted as the background of a class that extends javax.swing.JPanel

A background generally implies that the image fills the entire panel and the size of the panel is the same as the size of the image. Therefore when you paint the image the code should be:

```
g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
```

So the image is always painted at the top left of the panel.

When the panel is added to the frame, the layout manager will set the location of the panel.

> just with a different position

```
pCardPanel = new CardPanel(0, (height - Card.CARD_HEIGHT),
```

I would guess the problem is the "y" value is outside the size of the panel, so you don't see the image.

That is your preferred size does not account for the fact that you are attempting to paint the image at some location other than (0, 0) in which case the preferred size should be something like:

```
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x + width, y + height));
```

However, you don't want to do that, since each component should be independent of other components. It should not know or care that you are trying to position two panels above/below one another. It should just worry about painting its own image and let the layout manager worry about setting the location of each panel.

So what you really want to do is just paint the image at (0, 0) and let the layout manager determine the location of the panel.

You are already using the BorderLayout. So it is the job of the layout manager to set the location of the component in the "SOUTH" to some non-zero "y" value.

Comment: thank you for your long answer :) The mistake was that I took x and y as the position of the CardPanel on the parent JPanel while actually it was the location of the image on the CardPanel. Thanks for pointing that out to me.